# How to match this pattern in lua regex so it can catch what's inside the string

Tags: regex, lua, lua-patterns

I'm trying to put two asterisks in between words that a enclosed by underscores.

So far, I succeeded matching the pattern when it's just one word inside the underscores, if there's a space in the middle, the pattern fails.

How do I write the correct pattern to find the words in between the underscores and put asterisks in between them? Here's a MWE of my code:

```
function string:add(start, fim, word)
    return self:sub(1,start-1) .. "**" .. word .. "**" .. self:sub(fim+1)
end

regex = "In this string I'm putting _many_ words to test if I _wrote_ the code right to _match patterns_."

while regex:find("_(%w+)_") ~= nil do
    start, fim = regex:find("_(%w+)_")
    regex = regex:add(start, fim, regex:match("_(%w+)_"))
end

print(regex)
```

The output is:

> In this string I'm putting `**many**` words to test if I `**wrote**` the
>   code right to `_match patterns_`.

As it can be seen, in `_match patterns_` there are two words and a space, so my pattern `_(%w+)_` skips it. How do I include it too?

Comment: may be replace `gsub("_","**")` ? or you need to find the words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply find the characters between underscores excluding space at the beginning:

```
local str = "In this string I'm putting _many_ words to test if I _wrote_ the code right to _match patterns_."

print(str:gsub("_([^%s].-)_","**%1**"))

-- find the words --
for words in str:gmatch("_([^%s].-)_") do
  print(words)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a set using `[]` and define that set to allow for alphanumeric characters and spaces:

```
regex:find("_([%w%s]+)_")
```

Here is a resource where you can learn more about lua patterns:

> [FHUG: Understanding Lua Patterns](https://www.fhug.org.uk/wiki/wiki/doku.php?id=plugins:understanding_lua_patterns)